# With Yocto, how can I add a lot of files to an image?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

How can I add a lot of files to an image with a BitBake recipe?

The pattern that I follow to add files to an image is the following:

```
SRC_URI += "file://bar"
do_install () {   
    install -m 0775 ${S}/bar/baz/foo.txt ${D}${prefix}/test 
}
FILES_${PN} += "${prefix}"
FILES_${PN} += "${prefix}test"
FILES_${PN} += "${prefix}test/foo.txt"
```

Which works great for a few files. However, this can be really tedious for large amounts of files.  The problem seems to be that I need to specify each file that I want to package. Is there some way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the files are in a single directory you can just put the directory in `FILES` and it will recurse for you.  So if you had another 100 files in `${prefix}/test` then `FILES_${PN} = "${prefix}/test"` would package them all in `$PN`.

Comment: Thanks! While your method really speeds things up, it runs into errors for directories that are required to be placed in separate packages; for example, I have a `.debug` directory which BitBake requires placed in the `${PN}-dbg` package. I'm still manually packaging all these different directories.  Is this a necessary step?

Comment: If you set the ordering properly then this isn't a problem: PN-dbg should be before PN in PACKAGES.  Then you can do

FILES_PN = "/foo/bar"
FILES_PN-dbg = "/foo/bar/.debug"